# Indentation without tabs

Tags: tabs

What is the difference between `indent-tabs-mode` and `tab-always-indent`?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question, if that makes sense. The first sentence is a good question, but none of the rest has anything to do with it.

Comment: The question is unclear. What's the relation between the question hinted in the title and the question posed in the question body? What research have you done - have you looked at the descriptions of `indent-tabs-mode` and `tab-always-indent`? If so, can you be specific about what it is that you don't understand about the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the help for any variable by typing `C-h v` which runs the command `describe-function`.

`tab-always-indent` adjusts the behavior of the TAB key. As the documentation says:

```
Controls the operation of the TAB key.

If t, hitting TAB always just indents the current line.
If nil, hitting TAB indents the current line if point is at the left margin
or in the line's indentation, otherwise it inserts a "real" TAB character.
If complete, TAB first tries to indent the current line, and if the line
was already indented, then try to complete the thing at point.
```

Meanwhile `indent-tabs-mode` controls what character(s) to insert into the file when indenting a line:

```
Indentation can insert tabs if this is non-nil.
```

This is the most basic way you can choose between spaces or tabs for indentation.

Comment: To change `indent-tabs-mode`, there is the possibilities to use `setq-local`, `setq-default` or `setq`.  I think `setq-default` only changes the behaviour for major modes where the variable has not been set.

Comment: That is a separate question, unrelated to `indent-tabs-mode`. You should ask it separately.